# Inno Setup: update required size after unchecking components programmatically

Tags: inno-setup

Let's say I want to uncheck components 3-5:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var i: integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then
    { 0 based index }
    for i:= 2 to 4 do begin
      WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[i] := False;
    end;
end;
```

It works fine, they are disabled but total required size at the bottom of the window still shows value for all components. Is there a way to update it?

**Edit:** tried replacing

```pascal
WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[i] := False;
```

with

```
WizardForm.ComponentsList.CheckItem(i, coUncheck);
```

but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it! [Support Classes Reference](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses) page shows that `TWizardForm.ComponentsList` has property `OnClickCheck` which seems to be a pointer to unexposed [`TWizardForm.ComponentsListClickCheck`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Wizard.pas#L2398) procedure. All I neded to add was one line:

```
WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck(nil);
```

Full example:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var i: integer;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
    { 0 based index }
    for i:= 2 to 4 do begin
      WizardForm.ComponentsList.CheckItem(i, coUncheck);
    end;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck(nil);
  end;
end;
```